# Connecting to Ms dynamics nav web services from android

Tags: android, web-services, soap, dynamics-nav, dynamics-nav-2013

I'm trying to call a ms dynamics Nav (2013 R2) web service from an android application using Ksoap libreries, but i keep getting this exception "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:size<=0" ! I do not know what can be the reason! Can you help me please?!

this is my code:

```
        import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.Authenticator;
    import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.ksoap2.HeaderProperty;
    import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
    import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
    import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;


    public class Main extends Activity {
        private final String namespace = "urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/MonService";
        private final String url = "http://[@ip]:7047/DynamicsNAV71/WS/ATLAS%20AUTO/Codeunit/MonService";   
        private final String soap_action = "urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/MonService:Hello";
        private final String method_name = "Hello";
        String great="";
        TextView txt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

   txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    Button bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
    bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            new Task().execute();


        }
    }) ;


}

public String maMethode(){
    try
    {
          SoapObject request = new SoapObject(namespace, method_name);


          //Property which holds input parameters
            PropertyInfo celsiusPI = new PropertyInfo();
            //Set Name
            celsiusPI.setName("par");
            int n=123;
            //Set Value
            celsiusPI.setValue(n);
            celsiusPI.setType(int.class);
            request.addProperty(celsiusPI);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);


          //envelope.bodyOut=request;
           envelope.dotNet = true;   
           envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);   
           HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(url);    
           try{

                List<HeaderProperty> headerList = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
                headerList.add(new HeaderProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + org.kobjects.base64.Base64.encode("domain\\user:password".getBytes())));
               transport.call(soap_action, envelope);   
           }catch(IOException e )
           {
               e.printStackTrace();
              // System.out.println(e.toString()+"1");
               great=e.toString();
           }
           catch(XmlPullParserException e)
           {
               e.printStackTrace();
               //System.out.println(e.toString()+"2");
               great=e.toString();
           }

           if(envelope.bodyIn != null){
               SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse(); 

               great= result.toString();
           }
           return great;


    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
       // System.out.println(e.toString()+"" );
        great = e.toString();
        return great;

    }

}



public class Task extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        great=maMethode();
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        //Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground");
        txt.setText(great);
    }



}}
```

this is the wsdl:

```
        <definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/MonService" targetNamespace="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/MonService">
    <types>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/MonService">
    <element name="Hello">
    <complexType>
    <sequence>
    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="par" type="int"/>
    </sequence>
    </complexType>
    </element>
    <element name="Hello_Result">
    <complexType>
    <sequence>
    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="return_value" type="string"/>
    </sequence>
    </complexType>
    </element>
    </schema>
    </types>
    <message name="Hello">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:Hello"/>
    </message>
    <message name="Hello_Result">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:Hello_Result"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="MonService_Port">
    <operation name="Hello">
    <input name="Hello" message="tns:Hello"/>
    <output name="Hello_Result" message="tns:Hello_Result"/>
    </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="MonService_Binding" type="tns:MonService_Port">
    <binding xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <operation name="Hello">
    <operation xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" soapAction="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/MonService:Hello" style="document"/>
    <input name="Hello">
    <body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" use="literal"/>
    </input>
    <output name="Hello_Result">
    <body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" use="literal"/>
    </output>
    </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="MonService">
    <port name="MonService_Port" binding="tns:MonService_Binding">
    <address xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" location="http://@ip:7047/DynamicsNAV71/WS/ATLAS%20AUTO/Codeunit/MonService"/>
    </port>
    </service>
    </definitions>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a piece of software like [WCF Storm](http://wcfstorm.com/wcf/wcfstorm-lite.aspx) to test the Web Service endpoint and ensure you're not missing any parameters (E.g. Hello).

Otherwise we need some more detail about what you're exposing from NAV, e.g. Page, Codeunit, Query. This will give your WSDL some context rather than a Hello overload :)

Comment: thanks  :)
I'm calling  a simple codeunit that returns a text "hello world",  i'm using it just for test!
Is the authentication code correct?!
This is my first experience with android and Nav!!

Comment: when I tried the WS  on WCF Storm, it tels me "401 Unauthorized" 
is there any configuration for the NAV instance(I already enabled  SOAP services)?

Comment: Yup, in the global configuration there is  an authentication option for Windows Authentication.

Comment: yes, I did that!
I'm if i have to configure the server (nav)!

Comment: Try toggle the "Use NTLM Authentication" option in the service tier setup.